# MySQL return results with words missing

Tags: php, html, mysql, search

I have a site with a search field that sells phones and tablets. If you search `Blackberry 9900` it returns no results as the product is called `Blackberry Bold 9900`. I need a solution that displays the relevant product if a word is missing.

I tried this:

```
$words=explode("_",$name);
foreach($words as $word){
   $whereClause.= ' product_name LIKE "%'.$word.'%" OR';
}
$whereClause=substr($whereClause,0,-2);
$productQuery='SELECT * FROM products WHERE'.$whereClause.' AND status=1 AND deleted=0 ORDER BY product_order';
```

If you search `Blackberry Bold 9900` then all results containing `Blackberry` are returned. **How can I fix this so the result is relevant?**

Comment: In your case - use `AND` instead of `OR`. Correct solution is to use `FULLTEXT` indexing for that purposes.

Comment: instead of like use mysql's match query

Comment: Something like, `SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH (product_name) AGAINST ('$words') AND status=1 AND deleted=0 ORDER BY product_order`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$whereClause.= ' product_name LIKE "%'.$word.'%" OR';
```

to

```
$whereClause.= ' product_name LIKE "%'.$word.'%" AND';
```

and

```
$whereClause=substr($whereClause,0,-3);
```

of course.

That will search only products which name contains **all** words in search box (but not necessary only that words).

Maybe MySQL FULLTEXT search is better approach but it is supported only for MyISAM tables before MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look into using [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) as the LIKE operator will not help you here.

Comment: use mysql's match query, that will do what you want, and change table type to innodb or myisam (1 of two search what is that),

Comment: Search for "PHP MySQL fulltext example". Here's one: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/9/3/18

Answer (score 0):

If You really want to use like operator, then You can try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  products 
WHERE title LIKE  '%Blackberry%9900%'
```

I mean with one operator You can use few % chars.

So with Your code it will be:

```
$words=explode("_",$name);
$whereClause=' product_name LIKE "';
foreach($words as $word){
   $whereClause.= '%'.$word;
}
$whereClause.='%"';
$productQuery='SELECT * FROM products WHERE'.$whereClause.' AND status=1 AND deleted=0 ORDER BY product_order';
```

But if Your table with products will be big(>600k rows maybe), this one will be slow.
So it should be better to use FULLTEXT as it is faster if use it proper, how i know.